# Why do most PHP frameworks use set/get for Session variables?

Tags: php, class, session, frameworks

I am very curious as to why all the main PHP frameworks like zend use setter and getter methods to set and get basic **$_SESSION['user']** variables?  I am doing it myself right now but I really don't know why I am, other then the fact that I see it being done fairly often by others now.  So in theory at least, it seems like wrapping these into a class would just add more overhead and I just want to know if there is any reasoning behind this trend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason is that most of them allow you to store the session in a different way like a database. So you can always use get/set no matter how your session is handled.

EDIT: CodeIgniter for example checks if the session is valid after it got called (IP, Browser). So you don't have to call a "check function" right after you called **session_start()**.

Comment: That is the exact reason that I though until I realized that this can be done without wrapping it in a class, you can set the default session handler to use database without using a class or function

Comment: Yes, you can set your default session handler to be database driven, but the classes that implement sessions often have additional functionality built in like caching or a different method for storing session data in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Its so that you can lazy load the session - normally you would have to run session_start() before accessing any session variables, by using getters and setters, you can have this action performed on demand.